# Text-Decoration: none Not working for links?

Tags: html, css

`text-decoration: none;`   Is not working... My browser is Chrome, and the code is below:

[image]

```css
.hotbar li {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  margin: 0 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="hotbar">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:64310/about.html" target="_blank">About</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:64310/platforms.html" target="_blank">Platforms</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:64310/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to target the `a` tag, not the `li`.  Try `.hotbar li a {`.

Comment: should be  .hotbar li a

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the text-decoration from the anchor. So change your selector to `.hotbar li a`

```css
.hotbar li a {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  margin: 0 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="hotbar">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:64310/about.html" target="_blank">About
                        </a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:64310/platforms.html" target="_blank">Platforms
                        </a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://127.0.0.1:64310/contact.html" target="_blank">Contact
                        </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Really worth an answer? Comment and delete is enough I would think

Comment: Yes. I suggest you delete it and let OP delete their question based on the comment under the question. I voted to typo-type close this

Comment: @mplungjan But it's not a typo. A typo would be something like `div > p > imag`

Comment: It is a typo-TYPE- SO decided to make it discussable what is a typo. There was a missng "a" and that is the solution and that was commented on the question and then it can be closed since OP has an answer and there are hundred of dupes and it is not useful to anyone but the asker

Comment: It wasn’t a typo. It is an error in the logic.

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092666/text-decoration-none-not-working-on-ul)

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164673/html-css-text-decoration-does-not-work)

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937444/text-decoration-none-important-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply it to the anchor tag, not the list item.

.hotbar li a {text-decoration: none;}

Comment: Really worth an answer? Comment and delete is enough I would think. AND vote to close